# I have a problem creating stored procedure when I put a field with /

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a field [Product/Services] in my table in sql server 2005. Now I want to create a stored procedure for that table, but it keep giving an error and when I put only Product in my table than stored procedure is working fine. Now I want to put [Product/Services] in my table so how can I do that?????

Comment: Is a bad ideia to use special characters has the name of the table or column.

Comment: share your code and error message you get

Answer (score 4):

it is always a bad idea to try to include special characters in a column/variable/parameter/table/view/procedure/etc names.  All of your code will have to dance around this bad decision **forever**.

Without any detail on your particular code and/or error message, all I can provide are these links on the the rules for naming things in SQL Server:

[Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx)

[Delimited Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027.aspx)

from the second link:

> Microsoft SQL Server does not
>   recognize variable names and stored
>   procedure parameters that are
>   delimited. These types of identifiers
>   must comply with the rules for regular
>   identifiers.

Your best bet is to just name the column something like `Product_Services` or  `ProductServices` and you can have local variables and parameters named `@Product_Services` or `@ProductServices`.

Your next best bet is to leave the table alone and just names the local variables as `@Product_Services` or `@ProductServices` even though the table column is named `[Product/Services]`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are properly quoting the name Product/Services as [Product/Services] whenever you are referring to it or using it of redefining it. [] are the quote characters in MS SQL Server.